# Excel: Look up function for combinations of cells in a single column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking to find the number of times a certain combination of values appears in a single column, I was hoping to do this in Excel but I'm starting to think it may not be possible.

As an example, I have a list that looks like a longer vertical version of this:
F1
F3
F2
F4
F1
F3
F4
F1
F3
F4
F1
F3
F4

And I want to know how many times a specific order (say F1 F3 F4) occurs, in this example 3 times (in my case the lookup sequences are 8 cells long). Is there a way to run over the whole column and identify the instances where this combination of cells occurs?

I'm running Excel 2008 for Mac.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example with 3 elements you can use a formula like this where your data is in `A2:A100`

`=COUNTIFS(A2:A98,"F1",A3:A99,"F3",A4:A100,"F4")`

Note: I assumed F1, etc were text values hence the quotes - if they are cell references then lose the quotes

You can extend the above for any number in the sequence, so your 8 should work, make sure you "offset" the range by 1 row each time